# C# ComboBox Mês - Definindo o SelectedItem

Tags: c#, datetime, combobox, selecteditem

Tenho que criar uma ComboBox somente com os meses do ano para tratar as contas a pagar do sistema.
Até aí tudo bem, o problema é que o cliente queria que estivesse selecionado o mês corrente no Load.

Eu quero trazer os dados dinamicamente, sem usar um ENUM com os valores digitados a mão.

**Como está o código:**

```
private void LoadComboBoxMonths()
{
    string[] arrayMonths = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName;
    forech(var item in arrayMonths)
    {
        Months.Add(item.ToUpper());
    }
    
    cboMesCorrente.DataSource = Monhts
    cboMesCorrente.SelectedItem = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("MMMM");
}
```

Esse ***SelecteItem*** acima não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Então tinha usado o `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName` para trazer os meses para o Array e **deu certo**.

Então pensei e utilizar a mesmo só que, ao invés de usar um Array de Strings para depois passar os valores para a List preferi passar diretamente para a List.

**Como Ficou no Final:**

```
private List<string> Months = new List<string>();

private void LoadComboBoxMonths()
{

    for(int i = 1; i<=13; i++)
    {
        Months.Add(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i).ToUpper();
    }
    
    cboMesCorrente.DataSource = Months;
    cboMesCorrente.SelectedItem = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month).ToUpper();
}
```

Parece uma solução simples, mas bati muita cabeça e não achei nada na rede para ajudar.
Espero que isso possa ajudar outras pessoas para não sofrerem o dia inteiro como eu sofri.
E espero também que não removam, pois se tivesse um artigo ou pergunta igual eu não teria sofrido tanto assim.
Perdi um dia inteiro pra fazer isso.